# ASP.NET Button OnClick within Repeater and LoginView

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I'm developing a ASP.NET website with a C# backend.  I'm having a problem with how to set an onclick event for buttons that are nested inside of both a loginview and a repeater.  The code works fine for displaying all of the other data (anonymous view displays only an error message) but right now the buttons just redirect to the same page and remove the repeater and all contents, whereas they're supposed to run a specific delete function.  The repeater, as it is right now, uses an alternatingitem template.  If I remove the buttons from the nested controls, they work.  I've tried this with buttons, linkbuttons, and imagebuttons.  I'd rather use the latter, if possible.  Is it possible to assign an Onclick to these buttons if they're nested like this?  If not, what approach should I use?

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginLinksView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
<AnonymousTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="errorlabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</AnonymousTemplate>
<LoggedInTemplate>
    <asp:Repeater id="Repeater" runat="server" >
    <HeaderTemplate>
     <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
     <thead></thead>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <tr class="Repeaterrow">
    <!--Additional code here-->

    <asp:ImageButton ID="delbutton" runat="server" ImageUrl=
         "~/Images/delete.png" Onclick="DeleteOnClick"/>        
    </tr> 
    </ItemTemplate>   

    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <tr class="Repeaterrow">
    <!--Additional code here-->

    <asp:ImageButton ID="delbutton" runat="server" ImageUrl=
         "~/Images/delete.png" Onclick="DeleteOnClick"/>             
    </tr>
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>

    <FooterTemplate>  
    </table>
    </FooterTemplate>

    </asp:Repeater>
</LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

Comment: Try to remove the alternating item template for now, to see if it works. Notice you are having a syntax issue at the OnClick right after the first button.

Comment: Just a typo...thanks.  The same thing occurs with without the alternating template.  It just loops back to the current page but doesn't display the repeater or anything.  It doesn't matter what is in the OnClick block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the problems with your approach

1- The button issues postback as it should. But you need to put some CommandArgument with to identify "key" or which row you are processing it for.

2- Re Bind your Repeater with source. Below is the sample code for you.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindRepeater();
}

private void BindRepeater()
{
    List<int> items = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        items.Add(i);
    }
    Repeater.DataSource = items;
    Repeater.DataBind();
}
protected void DeleteOnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton delbutton = (sender as ImageButton);
    //1- call your method with passing in delbutton.CommandArgument - it will give you key/ whatever you like
    //2- Rebind the Repeater here and that will bind controls again...
    BindRepeater();
}
protected void Repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton delbutton = (sender as RepeaterItem).FindControl("delbutton") as ImageButton;
    if (delbutton != null)
    {
        delbutton.CommandArgument = (sender as RepeaterItem).ItemIndex.ToString();
    }
}
```

and ASPX Repeater definition would change to

Thanks,
Riz

Comment: Change repeater to this <asp:Repeater id="Repeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater_ItemDataBound">

Comment: OK, I already had the repeater binding and everything set up pretty much like you have here.  You say to call the method with passing it to delbutton.CommandArgument...If the delete method that is ultimately being called in the original onclick event is defined as deleteRow(string itemnumber, string itemdpartment), what would be the syntax for passing this method to the command argument?  Also, do I need to specify commandname or commandargument on the asp:ImageButton tags in the markup?

Comment: @BigEMPin You can only pass in the CommandArgument and combine the data as something like itemnumber + "," + itemdepartment in it. And than on server side you can split it to get them and pass in your already message.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but I did get this working weeks ago by following this.  However, the OnItemDataBound line didn't seem to do anything.  I had to set EnableViewState="true" to get it working.  Thanks for your help.